# Javascript promise: catch flow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

In the following code, I want to be able to exit app when *foo* fails, but not when *goo* fails. My problem is that when *goo* rejects, it's getting caught in *foo*'s catch. Is there a promise best practice solution to this issue?

```js
foo().then(() => {
    return goo.catch(() => {
        //do something
        //reject but don't exit app
    })
})
.catch(() => {
    //exit app
    //reject
})
```

Comment: What is the point in rejecting after exiting the app? the app already exited there.

Comment: Just a point of clarification. "Foo's catch" isn't really foo's catch. Because `catch` returns the promise it is invoked upon, and because you are returning the result of `catch` inside the `then` callback, the context of the outermost `catch` call is actually `goo`.

Comment: @DanielArant and what if Foo is throwing/rejecting?

Comment: I believe you would have to call foo.catch(...) before foo.then(...) if you want to catch a rejection in foo. Notice the second paragraph in the "Chaining" section of the following article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Description

Comment: @DanielArant Exactly- hence the accepted answer :)

Comment: Yep, I was just supplying the "why."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the trick:

```js
foo()
.catch(() => {
    //exit app
    //reject
})
.then(() => {
    return goo.catch(() => {
        //do something
        //reject
    })
})
```

Comment: not sure why this doesn't get more upvotes -- it's a very clear approach, and doesn't need the recondite 'explanations' so many speak when discussing promises. Straightforward ordering of responses makes sense, doesn't it? Thank you, @nir-smadar

Comment: @narration_sd I'm not sure either, as this solution is simple and working :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't reject in `goo.catch` - you don't want rejection to propagate to the `foo.catch` handler.

```
foo().then(() => {
    return goo.catch(() => {
        // do something but don't reject
    })
})
.catch(() => {
    // exit app
    // reject
})
```

So you enter catch block and "recover" from error situation. By throwing/rejecting you pass exception further, in case of `goo` you don't want this.

Comment: the final `.catch` will of course still get triggered if the `do something` code throws any uncaught exception

Comment: @dfsq That won't do, because I don't want to swallow the failure of goo. I need the failure to propagate

Comment: To me *"I don't want to swallow the failure of goo. I need the failure to propagate"* contradicts with *"My problem is that when goo rejects, it's getting caught in foo's catch."*. Also check Nir Smadar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `return` from `goo.catch()` block (or call `Promise.resolve()`)

```
const gooError;

foo().then(() => {
    return goo.catch(err => {
        // set the error thrown in to gooError that is
        // declared before the promise chain
        // and then simply 'return'
        gooError = err;
        return;
    });

    // to ensure goo error is taken outside immediately
    // You can omit this if not required.
    if (gooError) return; 

})
.catch(() => {
    // exit app
    // reject
})

// check if there was any error by goo
if (gooError) {
    // handle goo error here
}
```

Comment: That won't do, because I don't want to swallow the failure of goo. I need the failure to propagate

Comment: So you want the `error` of `goo` after the promise chain has completed?

Comment: See my edited answer. Error of `goo` will be propagated down (to outside the promise chain).

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what you want to achieve in synchronous code:

```
function main() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Exit process");
        throw e;
    }
    try {
        goo();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("do something");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

You can achieve this by nesting catches:

```js
function foo() {
  return Promise.reject();
}

function goo() {
  return Promise.reject();
}

function main() {
  return foo().catch(e => {
    console.log("Exit process");
    // what would be point in rejecting if the process already exited anyway?
    throw e;
  }).then(() => {
    return goo().catch(e => {
      console.log("Do something");
      throw e;
    });
  });
}

main().catch(() => { console.log("Main is rejected"); });
```